# Programm freezes when attempting to fill a 2D array from txt file

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array, text, freeze, cycle

So, I need to look through the file and fill an 2d array with data from the file. I couldn't figure any better way to do that than this, but this code just completly freezes after first proper iteration, it checks first line, than nothing. Here's the code.

The idea is that I'm gonna look through all of the text in a source file, then I'm gonna check if a line contains something I need and, if so, I will make additions to my 2D array, that I will then write to a different txt file.

The text below are from the source file, from which I need specific data.

```
[Signal_SensorA1]
VariableNameIn       = 4,-,"HWI_wB100A1",,,       ;Name of hardwareendpoint Signal in
HW_DataType          = 1,-,2,R,1,2                        ;Datentype of hardwareendpoint (1=Byte, 2=Word)
HW_ByteSwap          = 0,-,0,R,0,1                        ;Byteswap of hardwareendpoint (0=Off, 1=On)
DataType         = 1,-,0,R,0,1                        ;internal datratype (0=integer, 1=unsigned integer)
Division         = 3,+,0.0005787037 ,R,0.0,100000.0;  ;value for one hardware bit (max_value - min_value)/27648
Offset           = 3,+,-8.0,R,-10.0,10.0;         ;Offset
MeasurementMin       = 3,+,0.0 ,R,0.0,100000.0;       ;value measurement minimal
MeasurementMax       = 3,+,27648.0 ,R,0.0,100000.0;   ;value measurement maximal
LowerLimitExternal   = 3,+,0.0 ,R,-100.0,100.0;       ;lower limit / external     
UpperLimitExternal   = 3,+,0.0 ,R,-100.0,100000.0;    ;upper limit / external           
[Signal_SensorA2]
VariableNameIn       = 4,-,"HWI_wB100A2",,,       ;Name of hardwareendpoint Signal in
HW_DataType          = 1,-,2,R,1,2                        ;Datentype of hardwareendpoint (1=Byte, 2=Word)
HW_ByteSwap          = 0,-,0,R,0,1                        ;Byteswap of hardwareendpoint (0=Off, 1=On)
DataType         = 1,-,0,R,0,1                        ;internal datratype (0=integer, 1=unsigned integer)
Division             = 3,+,0.0005787037 ,R,0.0,100000.0;  ;value for one hardware bit (max_value - min_value)/27648
Offset           = 3,+,-8.0,R,-10.0,10.0;         ;Offset
MeasurementMin       = 3,+,0.0 ,R,0.0,100000.0;       ;value measurement minimal
MeasurementMax       = 3,+,27648.0 ,R,0.0,100000.0;   ;value measurement maximal
LowerLimitExternal   = 3,+,0.0 ,R,-100.0,100.0;       ;lower limit / external
UpperLimitExternal   = 3,+,0.0 ,R,-100.0,100000.0;    ;upper limit / external       
[Signal_SensorA3]
VariableNameIn       = 4,-,"HWI_wB100A3",,,       ;Name of hardwareendpoint Signal in
HW_DataType          = 1,-,2,R,1,2                        ;Datentype of hardwareendpoint (1=Byte, 2=Word)
HW_ByteSwap          = 0,-,0,R,0,1                        ;Byteswap of hardwareendpoint (0=Off, 1=On)
DataType         = 1,-,0,R,0,1                        ;internal datratype (0=integer, 1=unsigned integer)
Division         = 3,+,0.0005787037 ,R,0.0,100000.0;  ;value for one hardware bit (max_value - min_value)/27648
Offset           = 3,+,-8.0,R,-10.0,10.0;         ;Offset
MeasurementMin       = 3,+,0.0 ,R,0.0,100000.0;       ;value measurement minimal
MeasurementMax       = 3,+,27648.0 ,R,0.0,100000.0;   ;value measurement maximal
LowerLimitExternal   = 3,+,0.0 ,R,-10.0,10.0;         ;lower limit / external
UpperLimitExternal   = 3,+,225.0 ,R,-10.0,100000.0;   ;upper limit / external       
[LoadCell]
EnableSensorA1 = 0,+,1,R,0,1;
EnableSensorA2 = 0,+,1,R,0,1;
EnableSensorA3 = 0,+,1,R,0,1;
InvertSensorA1 = 0,-,0,R,0,1                     ;Invert sensor value
InvertSensorA2 = 0,-,0,R,0,1                     ;Invert sensor value
InvertSensorA3 = 0,-,0,R,0,1                     ;Invert sensor value
TimeDisableObservLimits = 1,-,250,R,-1,300                ;
[LoadCell/Compensation]
K11 = 3,+,8.5019,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation xc = f(x)
K12 = 3,-,0.0006,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation xc = f(y)
K13 = 3,+,0.0073,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation xc = f(z)
K21 = 3,-,0.0034,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation yc = f(x)
K22 = 3,+,0.6599,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation yc = f(y)
K23 = 3,-,0.0018,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation yc = f(z)
K31 = 3,-,0.0094,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation zc = f(x)
K32 = 3,-,0.0006,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation zc = f(y)
K33 = 3,+,0.6621,R,0.0,100000.0   ; compensation zc = f(z)
```

And here's the code that I wrote.

```
        string[] text = File.ReadAllLines(localpath);
        foreach (string line in text)
        {
            for (i = p; i < 100; i++)
            {
                end = false;
                for (j = 0; j < 1000; i++)
                {
                    if (end)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    if (line.Contains("Signal_Sensor"))
                    {
                        sensor++;
                        FileBase[i, j] = "Signal_SensorA" + sensor;
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("Signal_PositionA"))
                    {
                        controlD++;
                        FileBase[i, j] = "Signal_PositionA" + controlD;
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("Division") && (controlD != 0))
                    {
                        FileBase[i, j] = "Division";
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("LowerLimitExternal"))
                    {
                        FileBase[i, j] = "LowerLimitExternal";
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("UpperLimitExternal"))
                    {
                        FileBase[i, j] = "UpperLimitExternal";
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("LowerLimit"))
                    {
                        FileBase[i, j] = "LowerLimit";
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("UpperLimit"))
                    {
                        FileBase[i, j] = "UpperLimit";
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("LoadCell"))
                    {
                        loadcell = true;
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("PositionSensor"))
                    {
                        possensor = true;
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("EnableSensorA" + smth))
                    {
                        smth++;
                        FileBase[i, j] = "EnableSensorA" + smth;
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    else if (line.Contains("InvertSensorA"))
                    {
                        smth++;
                        FileBase[i, j] = "InvertSensorA" + (smth - 3);
                        FileBase[i, j + 1] = Convert.ToString(CommaClear(Value));
                        end = true;
                    }
                    if (smth ==6)
                    {
                        smth = 0;
                        end = true;
                    }
                    
                }
                p = i;
                break;
            }
        }
```

What am I doing wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this line correct? `for (j = 0; j < 1000; i++)` Shouldn't it be j++ or am I missing something here?

Comment: @Tomsen Oh, yes, my bad, thank you for pointing that one out. I'm going to add additional comment if that one will somehow fix it all.

Comment: It wouldn't surprise me if that would solve your problem, because it seems that your program doesn't freeze at all, but is stuck in an infinity loop.

Comment: @Tomsen. Welp, you were right, a little mistake made me pulling out hair on my head for a whole day. Thank you!

Comment: No problem and btw welcome on Stack Overflow